# Cannot find application.html.haml in a new Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I want to create Rails 3 app just to update myself, but I have strange issue.

I have created `welcome#index` action using

```
rails generate controller welcome#index
```

(I have `haml-rails` gem) and I observe that a new view `index.html.haml` has been created. This action is my root_path, so in `localhost:3000` I get content of this view.

I had `application.html.erb` which I have changed manually to `application.html.haml` and I have added `layout 'application'` in ApplicationController, but I get

```
Template is missing

Missing template layouts/application with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}
```

now, any ideas why ?

Maybe some code snippets:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout "application"
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

the file is in place:

```
mkk:~/projects/rails/gifts/app/views/layouts$ ls
application.html.html
```

Comment: You don't need to specify layout name for `application.html.haml`. Just remove `application.html.erb`

Comment: Please format code/command examples  in your post using backticks (`)

Comment: @ck3g I used mv command, there is no application.html.erb anymore.

Comment: I'm not using `layout "application"` and it's works for me http://pastie.org/5336647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ls` shows the layout file is called `application.html.html`, change it to `application.html.haml`.

Comment: I have just figured it out myself :) but before I typed the answer myself you have posted it here. I will of course accept it